# JavaScript function that composes other functions to create a master function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I wrote a little `Compose` function, which takes a variable number of arguments of type `function` and then calls each of those in order, passing in the value of the previously called function.

My function works just like I want it to, however since the function provides a way to program functionally, I figured it's application should be functional as well--but it's not.

The `Compose` function:

```
const Compose = (...functions) => {
    return val => {
        let i = 0,
            len = functions.length,
            fnResult = functions[i](val);

        while (++i < len) {
            fnResult = functions[i](fnResult);
        }

        return fnResult;
    };
};
```

Application:

```
const add7 = num => num + 7;
const squared = num => num * num;
const subtract13 = num => num - 13;

const add7ThenSquareThenSubtract13 = Compose(add7, squared, subtract13);

add7ThenSquareThenSubtract13(5);   // 131
add7ThenSquareThenSubtract13(0);   // 2
add7ThenSquareThenSubtract13(100); // 11436
```

What it's doing under the hood:

```
// Let's say 'val' is 5.

// 1. Call add7(val), result is 12.
// 2. Call squared(12), result is 144
// 3. Call subtract13(144), result is 131

// subtract13( squared( add7(val)  ) ) === 131
```

Anyone have any idea how I can make the logic inside the `Compose` function more functional? I am having a hard time since I am just now learning to think in a functional way. Is it even possible? I don't know of any ways to loop an array without using `for` or `while`.

**UPDATE:**

Never mind, I figured it out. Didn't think I could use `reduce` for this but I suppose I can:

```
const Compose = (...functions) => {
    return val => {
        return functions.reduce((prevVal, currFunc) => {
            return currFunc(prevVal);
        }, functions[0](val));
    };
};
```

It's not pretty, but it works--and it's functional. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One little suggestion on your reduce version is to make the initial value not the first function's result. This way, if ever the arguments *is empty* `functions[0](val)` won't call a missing function and throw up. Also makes `reduce` call the callback for each item, which makes it less of a cognitive burden.

Also, arrow functions that have expressions as its body implicitly returns the expression's value. You can have something as tiny as the following:

```
const Compose = (...args) => v => args.reduce((p, c) => c(p), v)
```